# How to move django project from ubuntu env to virtual env?

Tags: python, django

I have an existing django project which I have developed using python libraries installed in system and adding missing ones to the system. But now conflict has come for python-requests as system has 2.2 version but I need >2.5. Dont't want to uninstall and put newer one as it may break the OS. So now, I want to use virtual env and install packages there in complete isolation to that of OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the solution you're looking for is to download a different version of python without uninstalling your original, then start up `virtualenv venv`, but by passing in a path to the new `python.exe` file. Like this:  `virtualenv -p venv <path-to-executable-here>`, then just do `source bin\activate`, as usual. This starts the virtual environment using the python executable you passed to virtualenv through the terminal.

Also, this might not be the only way, but, there's something called [ModuleFinder](https://docs.python.org/2/library/modulefinder.html) which enables you to get a list of all the modules your script is importing--That is if you don't want to type them out manually, and you have extra modules installed (otherwise `pip freeze > requirements.txt` would do the job, and your new virtual environment would install all the packages in `requirements.txt`).

Comment: Done with second method. Thanks!!